# Auto-deletion rule for duplicate anti-SO posts

Tags: feature-request, spam, offensive

A lot of posts have cropped up lately by some disgruntled user reading something along these lines:

> I see that you are a new user to Stack Overflow, I suggest you to stay
>   away and use forums and other traditional websites/media instead of
>   this decadent and vanity-driven “community”. Your questions and
>   answers will only make the business of the lazy admins to grow and
>   your work to contribute will not matter at all when one retarded mod
>   or admin picks on you and starts censoring or suspending your account
>   for no reason. Greetings.

They've been deleted, but it's a pain and a waste of database space and time. Could a rule be created where posts within, say, 10 words of this aren't even added? They would appear to be added to the user, but they wouldn't exist. That would stop it for at least a while.

Comment: Heh! Indeed. Still, I think this will be sorted by some sort of IP ban on admin or dev level - the problem is not much different from that of a very persistent spammer.

Comment: I think automated filters are a bad idea in general, and ones you don't even notice even worse.

Comment: Is he still at it? I guess he doesn't want his account reinstated. However, I think the community has been pretty efficient in filtering these out. I don't really see the point of having an automated filter with all the potential issues that might cause.

Comment: So much butthurt, and I wasn't even remotely involved.  Its like I've been reborn!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A word filter for this specific instance

- would be easy to circumvent by just changing the wording a little bit
- wouldn't have allowed you to post a question about it (because it contained the offending words)
- Would probably add a lot of complexity on SO's end in the long run (as this won't be the last instance of something like this happening)

I think this needs to be (and probably already is being) sorted by some sort of IP ban on admin or dev level - the problem is not much different from that of a very persistent spammer, which is something the SO devs need to have defenses in place against anyway.